# Flutter: gitignore is... ignored

Tags: git, flutter, gitignore

I have a `gitignore` in my root folder, next to lib, ios, android, build... folders.

Inside it I have a bunch of ignored folders, one is `build/` but every time I do some changes this folder appears again:

> modified: build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/GTMAppAuth.framework/GTMAppAuth
> modified:build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher

I guess this has nothing to do with Flutter, that it's only Git, but this only happens with my Flutter projects, not with the rest

Comment: Is gitignore already committed with the build directory in it? If not, try removing the build directory entirely, add build to gitignore, commit, then trying building flutter again. They should no longer appear.

Comment: yeah, it was that. Removing again the build folder did the trick. It doesn't ignore it by default. Feel free to move that to an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment,

1. Remove the `build` directory entirely
2. Add `build` to `.gitignore`
3. Commit
4. Build flutter again

They should no longer appear.

This likely happen because there's some part of `build` directory already committed before `build` was added to the `.gitignore` file.